# Read from topic and write the messages in batches to a REST endpoint using reactor Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-webflux, spring-kafka, project-reactor, reactor-kafka

I am working on a project using reactive Kafka that consume messages from a Kafka topic and posts the messages in batches to a REST endpoint.
I am stuck on the batching part and sending that batch to endpoint. I need to read N messages (N here is configurable) from the topic and then sent that N messages to a REST endpoint. How can I read N messages using reactor Kafka? I have looked at the examples in https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/reference/#_overview but couldn't find an example that is similar to my problem. Any pointers on solving this will be really helpful.

Here is the code I have so far to read consume messages from a topic

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class Service implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("KafkaConsumerTemplate")
    public ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, String> KafkaConsumerTemplate;


    public Flux<String> consume() {
        return KafkaConsumerTemplate.receiveAutoAck()
                .doOnNext(consumerRecord -> log.info("received key={}, value={} from topic={}, offset={}",
                        consumerRecord.key(),
                        consumerRecord.value(),
                        consumerRecord.topic(),
                        consumerRecord.offset())
                )
                .map(ConsumerRecord::value)
                .doOnNext(metric -> log.debug("successfully consumed {}={}", Metric[].class.getSimpleName(), Metric))
                .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Error while consuming : {}", throwable.getMessage()));

    }


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        consume().subscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Lookinto `take` or `buffer` operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can use **#buffer(int)** operation for such purposes.

For your specific case:

```java
int bufferSize = 10;
return KafkaConsumerTemplate.receiveAutoAck()
          .doOnNext(consumerRecord -> log.info("received key={}, value={} from topic={}, offset={}",
              consumerRecord.key(),
              consumerRecord.value(),
              consumerRecord.topic(),
              consumerRecord.offset())
           ).map(ConsumerRecord::value)
            .doOnNext(metric -> log.debug("successfully consumed {}={}", Metric[].class.getSimpleName(), Metric))
            .buffer(bufferSize)
            .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Error while consuming : {}", throwable.getMessage()));
```

```java
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
   consume().subscribe(it -> {
      //it is a List of batched entities, here you can do whatever you want with your data.
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for